# Variable cambia a valor no esperado

Tags: java, java-swing, variables, revisión-de-código, variables-globales

Tengo un problema con una variable que se llama `contador`. La declaré con un valor 0 pero al correr el programa la variable `contador` tiene el valor de 8.

Ésta es la única parte del código que usa la variable:

```
public int comprobar(){
    separado = palabra.toCharArray();        
    for(int i = 0 ; i < largo ; i++){
        if(letra1 == separado [i]){
            aux [i] = letra1;
        }else{
            contador = contador + 1 ;
        }
    }
    return contador;
}
```

Éste es el código completo de mi programa, que es un juego:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String libreria [] = {"casa","programacion","goku","wolverine"};
    String palabra = null;
    int largo = 0;
    int numero = 0;
    char [] aux;
    char [] separado;
    String letra;
    char letra1;
    int contador = 0;

    public void buscar(){
        numero = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        palabra = libreria[numero];
        largo = palabra.length(); 
    }

    public void cambiar(){
        aux = new char[largo];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < palabra.length() ; i++ ){
            aux [i] = '-';
        }
    }

    public int comprobar(){
        separado = palabra.toCharArray();        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < largo ; i++){
            if(letra1 == separado [i]){
                aux [i] = letra1;
            }else{
                contador = contador + 1 ;
            }
        }
        return contador;
    }

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        //display.setEnabled(false);
        display.setEditable(false);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        display = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        recibir = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("palabra");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        display.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                displayActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("comprobar");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("limpiar");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        recibir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                recibirActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(display, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 166, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(recibir))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 69, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(46, 46, 46))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(display, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 96, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(recibir, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(43, 43, 43))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        buscar();
        cambiar();
        //System.out.println();
        //display.setText(builder.toString());
        display.setText(Arrays.toString(aux));
    }                                        

    private void displayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        display.setText("");
    }                                        

    private void recibirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        letra = recibir.getText();
        letra1 = letra.charAt(0);
        comprobar();
        System.out.println(letra);
        display.setText(Arrays.toString(aux));
        System.out.println(contador);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField display;
    public javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    public javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField recibir;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: al correr mas de una vez?

Comment: No desde el inicio, si pongo la letra correcta el contador inicia en 8 y cuando me equivoco de letra suma 9 en lugar de 1

Comment: Bueno.. a ver.. eso no es posible.. tal vez sea posible en C si no inicializaste una variable. Pero en Java no es posible. si empieza en 8, es porque en algun momento lo estas llevando a ese valor. Depuraste tu codigo?

Comment: yo supuse que contador porque es la unica que muestra. pero viendo el codigo, QUE DEBERIA estar en la pregunta y no en un enlace externo, veo que nunca, pero nunca volves esa variable a 0.

Comment: Es la única manera que sume 8 o más de 8, es que jamás la vuelves a reiniciar

Comment: Ya esta el codigo aqui, pero si lo incio en 0 cuando lo declaro y lo que quiero es que me sume de 1 en uno cada que no encuntre la letra por eso es " contador = contador + 1"  y si quito el else que me hace la suma si imprime el ocntador en 0

Comment: Eso es porque estás haciendo un for a largo que me imagino vale 9 por lo tanto se suma 8 veces por eso te da 8

Comment: ok entonces como puedo hacer para que al no encontrar la letra me sume 1 al contador?